# Passing Uri value from Dialog Fragment Class to an Adapter specifically on "onBindViewHolder"

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

I want to pass the value of `String image = uri.toString` to the Adapter specifically on "onBindViewHolder" to make it appear on the recylerview, but don't know how, this the code of my `uploadImageToFirebase(Uri imageUri)` method in my Dialog Fragment:

```
private void uploadImageToFirebase(Uri imageUri) {
    AddUserStudent addUserStudentCourse = (AddUserStudent) getActivity();
    String importClass = addUserStudentCourse.exportCourse();

    AddUserStudent addUserStudentSection = (AddUserStudent) getActivity();
    String importSection = addUserStudentSection.exportSection();

    user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    userId = user.getUid();
    StorageReference fileRef = storageReference.child("Students/" + FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(userId).child("Courses").child(importClass).child("Section").child(importSection).child("Students").child(sFullname.getText().toString()) +"/profile.jpg");
    fileRef.putFile(imageUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

            fileRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                    Picasso.get().load(uri).transform(new CropCircleTransformation()).into(studentImage);
                    String image = uri.toString();
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), image, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Image Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Uploading Image Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

and this is where I am trying to pass the value of that string image, on the adapter, specifically on "onBindViewHolder" (Note: Both the dialog fragment and adapter are part of one activity class):

```
public class AddStudentAdapter extends FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<AddStudent, AddStudentAdapter.myViewHodler> {

    /**
     * Initialize a {@link RecyclerView.Adapter} that listens to a Firebase query. See
     * {@link FirebaseRecyclerOptions} for configuration options.
     *
     * @param options
     */
    AlertDialog.Builder builder;
    public AddStudentAdapter(@NonNull FirebaseRecyclerOptions<AddStudent> options) {
        super(options);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull myViewHodler holder, int position, @NonNull AddStudent model) {
            holder.sName.setText(model.studentFullname);
            holder.sEmail.setText(model.studentEmail);
            holder.sAge.setText(model.studentAge);
//        Picasso.get()          This where I want to pass the uri on the dialog fragment
//                .load()
//                        .into(holder.imgStudent);

}
}
```

I've tried using bundle and intent by creating bundle in that dialog fragment below that uri and pass it in the main activity, after that I've created a method in the main activity wherein it stores the args of that bundle, and in the adapter, I'd call that method from main actvity.  But it seems that stuff doesn't work, and only provides a null pointer exception

P.S:
Already got the answer, I just make a:

```
public String getUri(String uri){
        this.setUri = uri;
        return uri;
    }
```

then on the onActvity result, I just call that getUri method pass the uri value to that method.

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: As I've said in the last part, I've tried using and intent but it doesn't work and it provides null pointer exception so I removed in the code above. Is there any way to pass the value of uri to the onBindVieeHolder?

Comment: `onBindViewHolder` is called for each element the query returns. So I'm not sure I understand, what you mean by "This where I want to pass the uri on the dialog fragment".

Comment: I want to get the value of that uri in the dialog fragment to the onBindViewHolder, but I can't.  The other thing that I am thinking is passing the string uri value to a model class on the oncreatedialog but I don't know how to pass the value of that uri (the uri that I am talking about that i would like to pass on fragment istelf and on the adapter onbindviewhodler is located below "onSucess (Uri uri)")